# Advantage of Solr over other DBs?

Tags: database, solr

As far as I know, Apache Solr Lucene project is a web-app which is used for rich text searching.

I just wanted to know:

- Why can't I use MySQL for that and just for rich text searching, why we use Solr?
- When all the other things can be performed using any DB ?

Comment: Full-text search is different from full-value search in that we need fast indexes for **any** part of the field (in practice, words and word stems). MySQL is crippled in this regard (algorithms are sub-optimal, performance is not very good); real RDBMSes (like DB2) have these facilities built in.

Comment: and what about full table scans and inversion indexing of Solr? Is this also possible in RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Solr an open source enterprise search platform from the Apache Lucene project and also it has many advantages like,

- Query language supports structured as well as textual search
- Uses the Lucene library for full-text search
- JSON, XML, PHP, Ruby, Python, XSLT, Velocity and custom Java binary output formats over HTTP
- Distributed Search through Sharding - enables scaling content volume
- A new auto-suggest component

**solr 4 adds NoSQL features**

Comment: "NoSQL features"? What does that even mean? That it can now *not query with SQL*?

Answer (score -1):

With respect to the first question, Solr is a non-sql database. The first advantage is that you don't need to define the identifier in advance, solr creates the identifier based on the content. This feature gives this sort of database much more flexibility. In this article [you can find a deeper explanation of the diferences between sql and non-sql databases](https://www.solr-tutorial.com/queries-with-solr.html)